# Calling the controllers with same class name different modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Inside the controller of my app, I have two different folders. Inside the folders I have two controllers with same name as shown below:

```
/controller/a/xyz_controller.rb    
/controller/b/xyz_controller.rb
```

Both the above controllers contain different module names. Module name of "**/controller/a/xyz_controller.rb**" is "***a***" and module name of "**/controller/b/xyz_controller.rb**" is "***b***".

The name of my app is "**a**". Inside routes.rb, I have something like this :

```
get "reports/update_notes"=>"b::xyz#function"
```

but somehow it is calling the "function" of "**a**" by default.

How to call the function of a controller of "**b**" through routes.rb ?

Comment: I am not sure that there is enough information here to understand what you are trying to do.  Can you describe in more detail why you want this controller arrangement as it seems rather odd, and what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

```
match "reports/update_notes" => "xyz#function", :via => :get, :module => 'b'
```

is probably the most transparent, but get should also work the same way. if you want the module name as part of the pattern, you need to use path-style instead of class-style:

```
get "reports/update_notes" => "b/xyz#function"
```